# Regex Expression Java: 8 Character long, At least 2 digit, Alphanumeric Only

Tags: java, regex

Need some help making an expression that support a minimum of 8 Character, At least 2 digit, Alphanumeric Only

This is what I've tried:

```
^((?=.*\\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$
```

These string should pass:

```
Abjh23af
879789765
legoF111
```

These string shouldn't pass:

```
Danrad1d = Only contain one digit
FFJURi22@ = Contain a @ symbols
aj22b34 = String is less then 8
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? It is pretty easy to validate the input without it.

Comment: @ILoveCoding, I'm wondering how can you validate without using regrex in basic Java, It's not efficient to test the string character by charecter, where the regrex will do it for us easily

Comment: @ILoveCoding, how do you validate without regex?  I would believe regex would be the most easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your regex string from:

```
((?=.*\\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}
```

to:

```
((?=.*\\d{2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})
```

Simply moved one closing parenthesis.  However there is still a small bug, this only passes if the two digits are consecutive.  Need to add one more parenthesis pair!

```
((?=(.*\\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})
```

Complete (with one added test case at end to illustrate need for added pair of parentheses):

```
public class PasswordValidator {

  private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 20;
  private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = String.format(
      "((?=(.*\\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,%d})", MAX_LENGTH);

  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;

  public PasswordValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
  }

  public boolean validate(final String password) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
    return matcher.matches();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PasswordValidator pv = new PasswordValidator();
    System.out.println(pv.validate("Abjh23af")); // pass
    System.out.println(pv.validate("879789765")); // pass
    System.out.println(pv.validate("legoF111")); // pass
    System.out.println(pv.validate("Danrad1d")); // fail
    System.out.println(pv.validate("FFJURi22@")); // fail
    System.out.println(pv.validate("aj22b34")); // fail
    System.out.println(pv.validate("1abcdef2")); // pass (thanks to extra parenthesis)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
example.matches("\\w*(\\d\\w*){2}")
```

This code

```
String[] examples = ("Abjh23af\n" +
        "879789765\n" +
        "legoF111\n" +
        "Danrad1d = Only contain one digit\n" +
        "FFJURi22@ = Contain a @ symbols\n" +
        "aj22b34 = String is less then 8").split("\n");
for (String example : examples) {
    System.out.println(example + " - " + example.matches("\\w*(\\d\\w*){2}"));
}
```

prints

```
Abjh23af - true
879789765 - true
legoF111 - true
Danrad1d = Only contain one digit - false
FFJURi22@ = Contain a @ symbols - false
aj22b34 = String is less then 8 - false
```

Comment: Still not working correctly, still passes string with less than 8 character.

Comment: Your `example` variable contains the explanation  `= ...` behind, so the test result doesn't make any sense